# Acumatica - Custom Table and Screen

Tags: c#, sql, acumatica

I have been trying to create a new screen that is used for entering model numbers. I have been following documentation but I have gotten to the point where I am confused about how to go about an ID and a CD. I think this has something to do with the `IsKey` attribute. I have tried adding the `IsKey` to the modelCD but then you cannot insert any new records. I have also tried just making the ID a `PXDBInt` instead of `PXDBIdentity` with the same results.

It's worth mentioning that this error only happens when inserting new records and there are no records in the database yet. This is creating a full screen basically from scratch where most documentation uses SQL tables that are already created and I was pretty sure that the formatting of mine is correct. The ID is an auto incremented value and the CD is going to be the model number that is held and the one you can enter in the system since that the ID is just auto incremented. Below is all code provided and the error that I am getting.

SQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ModelNumber](
    [modelID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [modelCD] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [modelID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

DAC:

```
using System;
using PX.Data;

namespace ModelCustom
{
  [Serializable]
  public class ModelNumber : IBqlTable
  {
    #region ModelID
    [PXDBIdentity(IsKey = true)]
    public virtual int? ModelID { get; set; }
    public abstract class modelID : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region ModelCD
    [PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXDefault]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Model Number")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<ModelNumber.modelCD>),
    typeof(ModelNumber.modelCD))]
    public virtual string ModelCD { get; set; }
    public abstract class modelCD : IBqlField { }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

Graph:

```
using System;
using PX.Data;

namespace ModelCustom
{
  public class ModelNumberEntry : PXGraph<ModelNumberEntry, ModelNumber>
  {
    public PXSelect<ModelNumber> ModelNumbers;
    public PXSave<ModelNumber> Save;
public PXCancel<ModelNumber> Cancel;
public PXInsert<ModelNumber> Insert;
public PXCopyPasteAction<ModelNumber> CopyPaste;
public PXDelete<ModelNumber> Delete;
public PXFirst<ModelNumber> First;
public PXPrevious<ModelNumber> Previous;
public PXNext<ModelNumber> Next;
public PXLast<ModelNumber> Last;
  }
}
```

ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/FormView.master" AutoEventWireup="true" ValidateRequest="false" CodeFile="IN200099.aspx.cs" Inherits="Page_IN200099" Title="Untitled Page" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPages/FormView.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="cont1" ContentPlaceHolderID="phDS" Runat="Server">
  <px:PXDataSource ID="ds" runat="server" Visible="True" Width="100%"
        TypeName="ModelCustom.ModelNumberEntry"
        PrimaryView="ModelNumbers"
        >
    <CallbackCommands>

    </CallbackCommands>
  </px:PXDataSource>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="cont2" ContentPlaceHolderID="phF" Runat="Server">
  <px:PXFormView ID="form" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" DataMember="ModelNumbers" Width="100%" AllowAutoHide="false">
    <Template>
      <px:PXLayoutRule ID="PXLayoutRule1" runat="server" StartRow="True"></px:PXLayoutRule>
      <px:PXSelector runat="server" ID="CstPXSelector8" DataField="ModelCD" /></Template>
    <AutoSize Container="Window" Enabled="True" MinHeight="200" ></AutoSize>
  </px:PXFormView>
</asp:Content>
```

And finally the error:

```
Error: Inserting  'ModelNumber' record raised at least one error. Please review the errors. 

Error: 'Model Number' cannot be found in the system. 

   at PX.Data.PXUIFieldAttribute.CommandPreparing(PXCache sender, PXCommandPreparingEventArgs e) 
   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnCommandPreparing(String name, Object row, Object value, PXDBOperation operation, Type table, FieldDescription& description) 
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.PersistInserted(Object row) 
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Persist(PXDBOperation operation) 
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist(Type cacheType, PXDBOperation operation) 
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist() 
   at PX.Data.PXSave`1.d__2.MoveNext() 
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__31.MoveNext() 
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__31.MoveNext() 
   at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.tryExecutePendingCommand(String viewName, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, Object[] searches, Object[] parameters, PXFilterRow[] filters, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, Boolean& closeWindowRequired, Int32& adapterStartRow, Int32& adapterTotalRows) 
   at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments)
```

Any help on this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Looking at the InventoryItem DAC as an example, the InventoryID column in the DB is the key, but on the DAC it makes the InventoryCD the key field. Try to have the key in your example on the CD field and not the ID field.

Comment: When I do that, I cannot insert a record if I have the IsKey on the modelCD because it does not invoke the save button so, it will not save the insert.

Comment: if you enter your key values and other field value on the row does it not enable the save? Same for stock items... the CD value is entered (but no save available) until you at least enter a value into another non key field.

Comment: Yeah I was only have just one field that you are entering with nothing else, I added a description field and then it will save to the database. So I guess I will have to go with that as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a description field as well and added it to the SQL script as well as the DAC. I have moved the IsKey to the modelCD field. The purpose for the description field is to invoke the Save but still being able to use the selector for the modelCD and inserting the record.
Here is the updated DAC:

```
using System;
using PX.Data;

namespace ModelCustom
{
  [Serializable]
  public class ModelNumber : IBqlTable
  {
    #region ModelID
    [PXDBIdentity()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Model ID")]
    public virtual int? ModelID { get; set; }
    public abstract class modelID : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region ModelCD
    [PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "", IsKey = true)]
    [PXDefault]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Model Number")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<ModelNumber.modelCD>),
    typeof(ModelNumber.modelCD),
    typeof(ModelNumber.description))]
    public virtual string ModelCD { get; set; }
    public abstract class modelCD : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region Description
    [PXDBString(500, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Description")]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public abstract class description : IBqlField { }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

Here is the new SQL Query:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ModelNumber](
    [modelID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [modelCD] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [modelID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be part of your issue.  If you are creating a custom table directly using a SQL script then you'll need to make sure to include the company ID in the schema and it needs to be part of the Primary Key.  This is assumed in the DAC so you don't need it listed there.

[CompanyID] [int] NOT NULL,